# Ionic 2: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The platform "andorid" does not appear to have been added to this project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Got the following error while running the porject:

```
(node:5692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The platform "andorid" does not appear to have been added to this project.
    at Object.getPlatformApi (C:\Users\sivaramakrishnan.m\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\platforms\platforms.js:46:15)
    at C:\Users\sivaramakrishnan.m\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:54:38
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\sivaramakrishnan.m\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:52:47
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\sivaramakrishnan.m\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\sivaramakrishnan.m\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\sivaramakrishnan.m\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\sivaramakrishnan.m\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\sivaramakrishnan.m\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
(node:5692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5692) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in the platform: "andorid" instead of "android"

Have you checked the command that you use to build?